# Noises generated by OpAmp driving 50 ohm load

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, linear, distortion

I am trying to drive a 50 ohm with 300mV, 15khz sine wave using an OpAmp. The chip I am using is [ADA4610](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4610-2_4610-4.pdf).

However, I found that there are noises of 15kHz(4mV Vpp) and 30kHz(3mV Vpp) at the power rails of the opamp. The noises even influence our DC power supply.

The spurious signals are caused by the output of the OpAmp. And I guess  it may be related with somehow load current, since when the load is disconnected from output of the OpAmp, the spurious signals disappear.

The maximum current used by OpAmp is only 6mA and it influences our power supply already. How to design to reduce the noises greatly? We are expecting high linearity signals without distortion. The noises at 15khz that can be accepted is 40uV.

Comment: Signals that are present only at certain frequencies are not called noise but "spurious signals". A property of noise is that there is no single frequency, it contains ALL frequencies (some more, some less). Is there something in your setup that uses a 15 kHz signal ? A switching power supply perhaps ? Then you need to apply more supply filtering to prevent the signal from reaching your opamp. The 30 kHz is just 2 x 15 kHz so a harmonic, if you eliminate the 15 kHz chances are the 30 kHz is also gone.

Comment: The 15kHz you are seeing at the power supply terminals is very probably from your own 15kHz output, probably caused by a less than optimal interconnect radiating this signal. As noted, the 30kHz is the second harmonic, generated by the amplifier in all likelihood.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the spurious signals are caused by output of the opamp. I have updated the post, could you have a look?

Comment: Circuit diagram? PCB layout? Is the 300mV rms or peak-to-peak? Why is 40uV the maximum acceptable power supply ripple?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I will update designs later, thanks!   300mV is amplitude. 40uV is needed because power supply also provides source to other devices.

Comment: By 'amplitude' you mean the rms voltage, right? Can you show us the waveforms of the noises? What are the other devices that can't accept more than 40uV noise on their power supply rails?

Comment: Have you got decoupling capacitors on the power supply lines?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to think about...

1. Are you sure that you are properly measuring the signal in the power supply lines of the OpAmp? Improper placement of the scope probe ground could account for all of the signal that you see on the power supply lines.
2. Do you have proper power supply bypassing on the V+ and V- pins of the OpAmp? If not apply some good quality ceramic bypass capacitors to your circuit.
3. Did you build your circuit on one of those proto boards where bunches of wires plug into rows of holes? These things will have coupling between adjacent rows of contact holes and your plug in wires. Try building on a more normal circuit board (proto wired or PCBA).
4. What did you do with the other OpAmp(s) in the package? If you left it(them) all open and unconnected this may very well be root of the problem. Spare OpAmps in a package need to be wired up so that they do not cause problems.